# What are the point of webpack "runtime" files

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack today for transpiling just my core business logic code, but are still using a CDN for all external libraries like jQuery, AngularJS, etc.  I want to move these vendor libraries into webpack by using the `SplitChunksPlugin`, but when I followed an example I found here at SO I got the vendor bundle to get created, but at the same time it also created some extra files I am not sure about.

For every `entry` module I have declared in the webpack config, webpack not also creates a "runtime" version of these files"

For example I have a `company.productA.core.bundle.js` taht I have been using for a while but after adding the config for the split chunks I now also get a `company.runtime~productA.core.bundle.js`. Webpack has done the same for the other 8 modules I have being created.

I have tried searching for what these are but don't see anything about them on both the webpack documentation and SO.

Can someone explain to me what these files are meant for?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Each of the runtime files contains code that enables loading of your chunks. If you open any of those runtime files, you will see code that loads your chunks via Jsonp.  Since you have asked webpack to split chunks, you are now free to load any chunk any time. Hence for each chunk, webpack emits these runtime files so that it can handle requires correctly.

Comment: Hmm interesting, so does that mean I want to load the "runtime" files into my HTML script tags so that the chunks can get loaded? I am currently trying to load the non-runtime files but I just get "angular is not defined" on basically all of my external and internal libraries.

Comment: you need the runtime to webpack load anything else.

Answer (score 8):

If you split bundle to multiple chunks (e.g. for each page), and for some reasons want to use several chunks on one page, you could face some problems. For example, by default, when you need singleton, especially when import the same library in both chunks, each chunk would have a **different** instance of singleton or library, and it could be a problem.

To solve this and have only one instance shared between chunks, you need to use `runtimeChunk: 'single'` inside webpack optimization section.

So, webpack docs has this warning:

> Imported modules are initialized for each runtime chunk separately, so if you include multiple entry points on a page, beware of this behavior. You will probably want to set it to `single` or use another configuration that allows you to only have one runtime instance.

[More info](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk)

Comment: Similar to this question, i have got a problem to configure loading chunk dynamically in webpack 5 during runtime. There is a question asked with bounty: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76876247/how-to-configure-runtimechunk-with-precompiled-file-path-in-webpack-5-or-alterna

@Oleg - can you please take a look and help me understand this in detail to change the settings