# What are the purpose for gatsbyjs built output files

Tags: gatsby

Gatsby.js comes with best practices, optimized code, and components but I do not understand what the purpose of each generated files. Things like,

- Why there are `component--*.hash.js`?
- What is a `webpack-runtime-hash.js` file?
- What's the purpose of `webpack.stats.json`?
- Is `page-data.json` necessary for a page to render?

I attached a screenshot of the project I am working on for the reference. However, if you could point me to the document where it explains the purpose of each file would be useful too. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120336/what-are-the-point-of-webpack-runtime-files

https://webpack.js.org/api/stats/

Comment: thanks @YuryTarabanko for your quick response. I have updated my question to cover all my doubts